# Selenium C# Element Not Found Taking a Long Time

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium for C# to test a page.

Is there a way to quickly fail if the element is not found on the page?

I am experiencing if the HTML element is not found on the page the Selenium test a very long time and then eventually it fails. Recommendations on quickly failing if the element not found is appreciated!

```
return WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id(myTextBoxId)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to change the Timeout wait time at the beginning of your test.

```
// In C# you can use
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("Path to Driver");
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new Timespan(0,0,2));
```

This should now wait for 2 seconds for an element to appear before failing. You can set this value to anything you want.

Comment: That seems to speed up the test a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The search for element should fail right away if you do not use any `implicit` wait or `explicit` wait. If you are doing that please remove them. And, if you are mixing implicit and explicit waits then that's even going to make it slower. On the other hand, if you expect the element not to exist and want to quickly check if the element exists or not and proceed, use `findElements()` and `size()` on the list. Something like the following:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("something"));

if(elements.size()>0){
    //element exist
}else{
    //does not exist
}
```

Comment: I am using the FindElement(By.Id("ss")) which takes an eternity to fail since the element is not on the page.

Comment: I mentioned couple of known reasons of that kind of performance